# pairwise comparison within a column pandas python Biopython

Tags: python, loops, pandas, biopython

i have a large data set that i read in with pandas and i want to do pairwise alignment by pairwise2.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from Bio import pairwise2   #for pairwise alignments 
from Bio.pairwise2 import format_alignment   #for printing alignments out neatly
```

but here i will use a mock data set:

```
data = { 'sequence': ['ACAAGAGTGGGACTATACAGTGGGTACAGTTATGACTTC', 'GCACGGGCCCTTGGCTAC', 'GCAACAAGGGGGGATACAGCGGGAACAGTGGACAAGTGGTTCGATGTC']}

data = DataFrame(data)
```

look like this:

```
Out[34]: 
                                       sequence
0           ACAAGAGTGGGACTATACAGTGGGTACAGTTATGACTTC
1                                GCACGGGCCCTTGGCTAC
2  GCAACAAGGGGGGATACAGCGGGAACAGTGGACAAGTGGTTCGATGTC
```

my goal is to do a pairwise alignment within the 'sequence' column, so the first row compares with the second, then the second compares with the third, the third compares with the first, and so on for a larger data set.

my code :

```
for seq in data['sequence']:
   for a in pairwise2.align.globalxx(seq, seq):
      print(format_alignment(*a))   #this is just to print the alignment out neatly.
```

this prints out:

```
ACAAGAGTGGGACTATACAGTGGGTACAGTTATGACTTC
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
ACAAGAGTGGGACTATACAGTGGGTACAGTTATGACTTC
Score=39

GCACGGGCCCTTGGCTAC
||||||||||||||||||
GCACGGGCCCTTGGCTAC
Score=18

GCAACAAGGGGGGATACAGCGGGAACAGTGGACAAGTGGTTCGATGTC
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
GCAACAAGGGGGGATACAGCGGGAACAGTGGACAAGTGGTTCGATGTC
Score=48
```

which is close to what i want but it only compares the first to the first, second to second and third to third.

so i tried this:

```
for seq in data['sequence']: #for each 'sequence' column value
    for index, row in data.iterrows(): #for each row 
        for a in pairwise2.align.globalxx(seq, row['sequence']): #compare 'sequence' column value to each row of the 'sequence' column
            print(format_alignment(*a))
```

this gave out way too many lines of output i'm not even going to try to post it here.

my idea was to compare the 'sequence' value to the rows of the 'sequence' column, but the output gave way too many alignments than expected. i think the double loop is not the way to go here. **i guess my question doesn't even have anything to do with Biopython, just simply how can i do pairwise comparisons within one column?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the combinatoric generators from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
for seq0, seq1 in itertools.combinations(data['sequence'], 2):
    for a in pairwise2.align.globalxx(seq0, seq1):
        print(format_alignment(*a))
```